# Html.RouteLink not producing correct link even with correct route name

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following in _Layout.html

```
@Html.RouteLink("test", "CityWithTypeSpecified",  new {  country = Model.CountryCode, state = Model.State, city = Model.CurrentCity.SubDomainName, description = type.Description, id = type.TypeID })
```

When the inheriting page is served by the "City" controller, the link is generated fine, when the inheriting page is served by another controller, the link url is blank

here is my route

```
   routes.MapRoute(
           name: "CityWithTypeSpecified",
           url: "{country}/{state}/{city}/{description}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "City", action = "LoadByType" }
       );
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: For `routes.MapRoute`, try changing url parameter to this: `url: "{controller}/{action}/{country}/{state}/{city}/{description}/{id}"`

Comment: I have url's that look like this http://localhost:9609/ca/on/london/pharmacies/1 which no longer work because the route was changed to include controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it.. some of my items where null.. if you are having the same issue make sure your data is not null for any of the given fields.